# How to use LINQ in a .dib Polyglot notebook?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core, dotnet-interactive

I'm trying to use LINQ in a C# (Polyglot Notebook).

```cs
using System.Linq;

Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables().Values.Select(x => x)
```

But I'm getting the error:

> Error: (3,46): error CS1061: 'ICollection' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no accessible extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'ICollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[image: Screenshot VSCodoe]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the using statement, LINQ should be available/imported by default. The "issue" here is that `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables()` returns a non-generic [`IDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.idictionary?view=net-7.0) and it's [`Values` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.idictionary.values?view=net-7.0) is non-generic `ICollection` (which implements non-generic `IEnumerable`) which does not support much of LINQ's methods besides [`Cast`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=net-7.0), most of LINQ works with generic version of `IEnumerable`. So you can use `Cast` or `OfType`:

```cs
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables().Values
    .Cast<string>() // or `OfType<string>()`
    .Select(i => i);
```

Comment: Looks like I'm not the only one: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/58438

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables().Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
             .Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```